# maven 3.0+ Skip plugin execution on 'mvn deploy'

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3

I want to skip a plugin execution when I run the command 'mvn deploy'. Say in below example, I DON'T want to execute the 'properties-maven-plugin' in 'mvn deploy'

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>${session.executionRootDirectory}/xxxx.properties</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <tagNameFormat>@{artifactId}/@{artifactId}-@{version}</tagNameFormat>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
<plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin is bound to `prepare-package` phase, so I think you can not avoid it execution when deploying.

But, it is possible to create a profile that contains that plugin, such way you activate (command line, Jenkins configuration, ...) the profile when you want to run the plugin.

This way you can control whether to run it, but it is not an answer to your question, because this way you can not avoid the plugin execution on deploy.